# Clean registry of computers in network

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I have a network with mostly Windows 7 machines. I also use Spiceworks and sometimes it doesn't detect when a software application has been removed, because some leftover registry remnants are still present after the uninstall.

Is there any way I can scan the PCs in my network and clean up the registries on each one in an automated fashion?

Comment: If it's a domain network or you have a method to execute scripts, and assuming the registry entries are the same in each case, it should be a simple matter of creating a `.reg` file with the necessary modifications and executing it on each machine. if the registry entries differ (e.g. machine-unique identifier), then you'll need to do a little more scripting work.

Comment: @Moses - You should be very careful about "automatic" tools that touch the registry hive.  Great way to have unbootable systems or worst, a registry file that is jacked up.  Personally the only tool I would trust is ccleaner only because its 100% free and doesn't attempt to push their services as a `registry booster`

Comment: If you want to create custom scripts for specific tasks you can do that.  This way you can validate and verify the system works after the script it ran.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I am very wary of anything that claims to "speed up" my PC. I love CCleaner, and they have a network edition that would do exactly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately it is quite expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this "Hey Scripting Guy" blog article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/17/edit-the-registry-on-multiple-remote-computers-with-powershell.aspx) about remote-registry editing with PowerShell. It should get you started!

The particular important bits from this article are these:

```
$cred = Get-Credential iammred\administrator

Invoke-Command -cn (gc c:\fso\servers.txt) -cred $cred {pushd;sl HKCU:\software; ni HSG; New-ItemProperty -name forscripting -PropertyType string –path hsg -value "powershell rocks" ; popd}
```

- servers.txt contains a list of servers on your network
- `iammred\administrator` is your domain (or workgroup) credentials
- `HKCU:\software` is the registry key path
- `-propertyType` is the type of value
- `-value` is the value

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Normally I would @Bob, however, given that none of the details (registry paths, number of machines, workstation/domain environment) there is simply no more specific information to provide.

Comment: In that case, consider leaving a comment (e.g. requesting more information) rather than an answer.